# Single EJB responsible for logic and many clients

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm new to Java EE and I stuck with problem described below, I'll be very happy if you can help me.

I need to implement some logic (based on finite-state machine) on server. As I understand I should implement it as EJB, right?. The problem is that one client should be able to create such "object" and other clients should be able to connect to it. When all clients disconnects form object it should be destroyed.

Moreover such object performs some operations in loop and it have to be able to notify connected clients about particular changes.

So far I learned that EJB are oriented for single user session or for message-based communication. Neither of them fit my requirements.

Any hints how to design application for my problem? I should stick to Java EE 6.

Answer (score 2):

As @André suggests, the object with the finite state machine should be an `@ApplicationScoped` class, or `@Singleton` depending whether you need EJB functionality or not, to which clients can register:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StateMachine {
    private List<Client> clients;

    @PostConstruct
    public void create() {
        clients = new LinkedList<Client>();
    }

    public void register(Client client) {
        clients.add(client);
    }

    public void unregister(Client client) {
        clients.remove(client);
        if (clients.isEmpty()) {
            reset();
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        // resets the singleton, because the container manages its life-cycle
    }
}
```

The `Client` class can be an `@SessionScoped` classed that lives as long as the client session is valid. On initial request of the session-scoped class registeres itself to the singleton. You can then inform the clients about events by looping over the list. Whenever up-to-date data is needed, the `Client` class can be queried via request.

```
@SessionScoped
public class Client {
    @Inject private StateMachine machine;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerToStateMachine() {
        machine.register(this);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void unregisterFromStateMachine() {
        machine.unregister(this);
    }

    public void handleEvent(/*..*/) {}

    public /*..*/ query() {}
}
```

Be aware that you cannot send CDI `Event<>` from the `@ApplicationScoped` to `@SessionScoped` objects because their context is not available in the application context.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JMS `javax.jms.Topic` here, where one of your client can publish a message & others can listen to it.

Therefore, all the subscribed clients to that particular topic will get notified whenever a new message is being added.

Answer (score 0):

Try make your "object" a singleton ejb firing events to your connected clients - cdi observers.